# Backbone route queryString proof

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm looking the proper and faster way to ignore queryString on all my routes.

I found this [plugin](https://github.com/jhudson8/backbone-query-parameters) which is working fine; however, I just need to ignore the querystring and it'll be better to avoid include all that code.

I was trying to do something like this:

```
var queryStrip = /(\?.*)$/,
myRouter =  Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize: function(){
           this.on('all', function(){
           Backbone.history.fragment = Backbone.history.fragment.replace(queryStrip, '');
           })
        }
});
```

But, this approach is not working. Seems like history fragment is readonly.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried simply starting routes with "#" or "/" 
you can also try explicitly disabling push-state (although it should be off by default)

All the backbone apps I have easy access to a querystring before the # and navigation still works correctly